# Substituir valores Zero e Infinitos em uma matriz (R)

Tags: r, matriz

Na matriz do exemplo abaixo (retorno diarios de ações) :

```
       IBOV        PETR4        VALE5       ITUB4        BBDC4        PETR3
[1,] -0.03981646 -0.027412907 -0.051282051 -0.05208333 -0.047300526 -0.059805285
[2,] -0.03000415 -0.030534351 -0.046332046 -0.03943116 -0.030090271 -0.010355030
[3,] -0.02241318 -0.026650515  0.000000000 -0.04912517 -0.077559462  0.005231689
[4,] -0.05584830 -0.072184194 -0.066126856 -0.04317056 -0.066704036  0.000000000
[5,]  0.01196833 -0.004694836  0.036127168 -0.00591716 -0.006006006  Inf
[6,]  0.02039587  0.039083558  0.009762901  0.01488095  0.024169184  0.011783189
```

Eu gostaria de substituir os valores 0 (Zero) e Inf pelo valor da primeira coluna, na mesma linha que se encontra o valor 0 ou Inf.

Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Só para ver se eu entendi, você quer trocar 0 ou infinito pelos valores do Ibovespa?

Comment: Quero trocar os 0 e Infinitos pelos valores do ibovespa no mesmo dia.

Por exemplo a Vale5 na linha 3 teria o valor -0.022413418

A PETR3 na linha 5 teria o valor 0.01196833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pelas respostas, segue uma forma que foi respondida no stack em ingles que funcionou tambem  :

**infinite_na** é a matriz com os valores de ret == 0, infinito e -1

**bancodados_ret** é a matriz com os retornos diarios das ações e do ibovespa

```
 infinite_na <- bancodados_ret==0 | is.infinite(bancodados_ret)|bancodados_ret==-1
 infinite_na[is.na(infinite_na)]=FALSE
 bancodados_ret[infinite_na] <- bancodados_ret[row(infinite_na)[infinite_na], 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você poderia fazer algo tipo:

```
ind <- which(my.matrix==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
apply(ind, 1, function(x) my.matrix[x[1], x[2]] <<- my.matrix[x[1], 1])
```

veja se é isso mesmo que você queria.

No código acima, eu descubro a linha e a coluna de um padrão, e aplico uma função de substituição a matriz de índices. Não se esqueça de usar o operador de atribuição global "<<-" pois a função `apply` aplica a função apenas localmente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma. Abaixo `m` é a sua matriz:

```r
m[m==0] <- m[row(m)[m== 0], 1]
m[is.infinite(m)] <- m[row(m)[is.infinite(m)],1]
```